# RTOS experience

Tags: rtos

I have been working as an embedded software engineer on mostly 8 bit micro-controller firmware and desktop/mobile applications development for the past five years.

My work on a WinCE project (in which I got introduced to .NET CF) was short lived. I did use core APIs for interrupt processing, peripheral communication, etc...but again, not exactly a pure RTOS environment. In order to get together more solid experience for growing more in the embedded field, I want to work more with RTOSes.

Will buying an evaluation board with an RTOS and putting together a project at home be regarded as a good experience or will an online course be more useful? I am just not clear as to what will be regarded as good experience. Any suggestions or directions will greatly help me. I have a passion for the field but just a need a point in the right direction.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Regards,

Subbu

Comment: might be more appropriate for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest looking at either:

- FreeRTOS - an increasingly widely used open source RTOS with plenty of documentation on its own website.  There are commercially supported versions (SafeRTOS and OpenRTOS) too.
- Micro C/OS-II, either via Jean Labrosse's [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1578201039), or the [evaluation](http://www.micrium.com/page/products/rtos/os-ii) (or both of course).  The book's second chapter is a good general overview of a typical RTOS, the bulk of it describes the kernel in detail, and is less important if RTOS usage rather than implementation is your goal.
- [eCos](http://ecos.sourceware.org/); an extensive and scalable RTOS including capabilities extending beyond mere kernel scheduling and IPC.  The [one book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0130354732) on the subject does little more than collect information that is available elsewhere, such as that provided in the previous link.

For simple projects that just need a kernel, I would suggest FreeRTOS for cost, functionality, and support.  For more sophisticated boards with networking, filesystems, USB, etc., where perhaps a heavyweight OS such as Linux does not meet resource or real-time constraints, I would suggest eCos.  Micro C/OS-II is good if you want to investigate how an RTOS kernel works under the hood in great detail.

Before you buy a board, I suggest that you experiment with the x86 ports of some of the above in a VM on your PC perhaps, or use an old PC you are not otherwise using.

Answer (score 1):

Probably out-of-time :)

But you may also evaluate BeRTOS, an RTOS which provides drivers and libraries integrated in the operating system. If you want to have a taste of the OS, you can choose one of the several example projects that come with the system.

http://www.bertos.org/

http://www.bertos.org/download-en

Answer (score 0):

CoocoX is yet another RTOS mainly focusing towards cortexM3 controllers , It is similar to Micro C/OS-II , It is completely free and open source .  If you want to start learning embedded RTOS programming i would recommend take a stm32discovery board and put coocox .
Coocox comes with full support for stm32 microcontroller , including IDE and other tools.

http://www.coocox.org

Answer (score 0):

I think You'll be better try real environment and easily taking the embedded systems.

I recommend to use ,
STmicro Nucleo Evaluation board

http://www.st.com/web/en/catalog/tools/PF260320

And you can buy the eval kit . that's very cheap. < $20

And Using the MBED web-based IDE and compiler system.

http://mbed.org/

You can first trying the evaluation.
and Also there's RTOS stack using examples.

If you have some experience on small embedded system then, 
You can try FreeRTOS and Native gcc-arm compiler and toolchain for your own.

Have a good job and Enjoying the developing. ^^